# Why is the camera view matrix not changing the position of the point

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

```
glm::vec3 Position(0, 0, 500);
glm::vec3 Front(0, 0, 1);
glm::vec3 Up(0, 1, 0);

glm::vec3 vPosition = glm::vec3(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z);
glm::vec3 vFront = glm::vec3(Front.x, Front.y, Front.z);
glm::vec3 vUp = glm::vec3(Up.x, Up.y, Up.z);
glm::mat4 view1 = glm::lookAt(vPosition, vPosition + vFront, vUp);


glm::mat4 projection1 = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)1920 / (float)1080, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

   glm::mat4 VPMatrix = projection1 * view1;    

float testZ = 0.0f;
glm::vec3 modelVertices(-50.0f, 50.0f, testZ);
glm::vec4 finalPositionMin = VPMatrix * glm::vec4(modelVertices, 1.0);
Print() << finalPositionMin.x;
```

In the code if  i change the FOV value of  perspective than that affects the object drawn on screen for smaller values object size increases on the screen.

1. At FOV value of 45 the finalPositionMin.x is -50
2. At FOV value of 25 the finalPositionMin.x is -126

but if i move the camera closer to the object than that should also affect the object and more closer we come to the object the  finalPositionMin.x should be affected.

Why changing value the Z positon of camera is not affecting the finalPositionMin.x of  the object ?

Comment: You have to print `finalPositionMin.x/finalPositionMin.w`. To get a Cartesian coordinate, you need to divide the x, y, and z components by the w component.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that would give me value in NDC , but if i want to know what would be the  value in world space of x.

Comment: In your example,`finalPositionMin` is not in world space, it is in clip space. To get a world space coordinate you need to multiply `modelVertices` by the model matrix, but nothing else. `view1` transforms **from** world space **to** view space. `projection1` transforms **from** view space **to** clip space.

Comment: The perspective divide transforms **from** clip space **to** ndc.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you  now i understand the issue with my question.

Comment: Likely you confuse "window" coordinates and "world" coordinates. To get window coordinates ("pixel" coordinates) you have to "project" the ndc on the viewport. `x = width * (ndc.x+1)/2`, `y = height * (1-ndc.y)/2`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you very much , this is what i was looking for , Really appreciate your commitment to help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a Cartesian coordinate, you need to divide the `x`, `y`, and `z` components by the `w` component. You have to print `finalPositionMin.x/finalPositionMin.w`.

Likely you confuse "window" coordinates and "world" coordinates. In your example, `finalPositionMin` is not in world space, it is in clip space. To get a world space coordinate you need to multiply `modelVertices` by the model matrix, but nothing else.
Note, the view matrix (`view1`) transforms **from** world space **to** view space. The projection matrix (`projection1` transforms **from** view space **to** clip space. With perspective divide you can transforms **from** clip space **to** a normalized device coordinate.
To get window coordinates ("pixel" coordinates) you have to "project" the NDC onto the viewport (`width`, `height` is the size of the viewport):

```cpp
x = width * (ndc.x+1)/2
y = height * (1-ndc.y)/2
```